# How to change the default homepage in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, homepage

When browsing in Internet Explorer, I get the MSN homepage every time I go to Hotmail which is an account that's not used often but I cannot stop the homepage takeover.

How can I block the MSN homepage and disable it / change it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Start Internet Explorer.
2. On the Tools menu, click `Internet Options`.
3. Click the `General` tab.
4. In the Address box, type the web page address that you want for your home page.

   If you want the page that you are currently viewing in Internet Explorer to be your home  page, click `Use Current` and click `OK`.

[Click here for a detailed guide](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/155721-internet-explorer-home-page-add-change.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this go to "Tools" on Internet Explorer tool bar, see, addsite to start menu it is locked into the frame unable to add , now open internet option on tools see TABS  see how web pages are displayed in tabs , STOP,      erase create homepage tab, blank, now hit the tabs  now hit blank now put homepage try hit tab tab browsing setting  check only open first homeopage when internet explorer starts, make sure you see .your first home page then close try it it worked for me nomore msn startpage.

Comment: If you could clean this up using the formatting tools (http://superuser.com/help/formatting) so that the major steps required are clearer then it would be appreciated. As it stands this is nearly impossible to read as it is simply a long stream of words.  I have removed your email address as help should be provided here, not in private emails.